# Can we setup an area for beginner questions which cuts out some of the more specific questions people have

Tags: feature-request

I think that is would be a good idea to have an area where a someone new to home brewing can go and find lots of beginner type questions. This could maybe done through a tag "beginner" or maybe someone else has some good ideas.

It can include simple questions such as How to store fermenter after use, How long will bottled beer last?, What's the point of secondary fermentation? etc.

It will help people who are interested in getting into home brewing by showing them the FAQs for beginners  but not the specific questions people have such as Why does my beer taste a little like wine?, First time making cider, will it work well. etc.

Comment: We then need some criteria to define exactly what a beginner question is. Is beginner purely for totally new brewers? Does is cover just extract (which is what most new brewers use) or should other techniques, like partial mash be included?  If I am a beginner all-grain brewer, are they flagged as beginner questions?  Maybe beginner simply applies to any technique and covers basics needed in order to begin using that technique or process?

Comment: I don't think we should limit it to new brewers but anyone new to any topic within home brewing (kits, grains, cleaning, kegging etc.) I think the main reason would be to cut out the specific questions that people have about their own experiences (not that they are not useful questions) so then only questions that can help an understanding of the topics from a beginners point of view.

Answer (score 2):

As per my post on the Sept. 2013 self-evaluation question, why don't we pin the FAQs, beginner Wikis, and most helpful answers to the right of the landing page like www.reddit.com/r/Homebrewing does?

Comment: Having these links accessible would be good, but can this be done with the SE site format?

Comment: Missed this... @mdma: not exactly, but you can add them to the sidebar on the /questions/ask page. Well, I can anyway - so if you guys put together a list of topics you want linked to, ping me & I'll do so.

Answer (score 0):

good idea - a lot of the original questions that founded the site were beginner-level questions, but I don't think they've been tagged as such.

Comment: I have just added the tag on one of my existing questions so we will see how often it will be used. Is it worth people editing others questions with what they think can use the beginner tag?

Comment: I just noticed there is a tag "first-time-brewer". I'm imagine that serves the same purpose as the beginner tag?

Comment: I have never seen the "first-time-brewer" tag. I have added the tag "beginner" and have been updating my own beginner questions and some other users questions with it. I think the tag "first-time-brewer" is a little vague. As per your first comment on the OP it doesn't lend itself to people trying new things in brewing but not necessarily new to brewing.

Comment: I remember back a couple of years ago, an SE staff went through and removed all the 'first-time' type tags, as not really being particularly useful